# Easiest way to filter out particular values php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to filter out everything from key_people until the start of the name "Maynard" in the following string in php:

key_people = https://info.yahoo.com/management-team[[Maynard Webb]] Rest of String

So that I am left only with: "Maynard Webb Rest of String"

However I am looking for a generic approach that can be applied to most strings (having a format as shown below) as the string and name within could be be different. So in general how to filter out for a string with the generic format:

"key_people = Some value[[Name]] Rest of String"

To only return:

"Name Rest of String"

Please assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^.*?\[\[|\]\]
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.This will work if your format is fixed.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/7